# Escaping characters in JavaScript in a Jinja template

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I have a Jinja template which I am using in a Flask web application. However I am struggling quite a bit with a single line, which contains JavaScript which write html. It look like this, without any escaping:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') }}"></script>')</script>
```

If I run the application like this, the pages actually appear to be correct. But Visual Studio Code throws a bunch of warnings/errors:

[image: VS Code screen dump]

If I hover the text which has a red curly line underneath, it says: *',' expected. js*

I have tried a bunch of escape tricks, both from [JavaScript](https://w3schools.sinsixx.com/js/js_special_characters.asp.htm) and [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#escaping), but I cannot get anything to work. I feel bad just ignoring the VS Code warnings, at least without understanding what's going on.

What should I do?

**Update - Here are some of the solutions I have tried:**

Escaping with backslash:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ url_for(\'static\', filename=\'js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js\') }}"><\/script>')</script>
```

This returns the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError 
>   jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '\' at 2879

Using HTML code:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{ url_for(&#39;static&#39;, filename=&#39;js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js&#39;) }}"><\/script>')</script>
```

This reutrns the following error:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError 
>   jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected char '&' at 2879

Comment: Can you show what you tried and what you mean by it not working?

Comment: @NickParsons I tried so many different combinations, that I kind of lost track of them all (yes, that was kind of stupid). But I will add a few of the (failed) attempts to the post...

Comment: Try to escape with `raw` / `endRaw`: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#escaping